# Azure SDK Download link for 32 bit Windows

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-.net

Very Silly question. can someone quickly share me the Azure download link for 32-bit OS version from microsoft?

Regards,
Viswa V.

Comment: Azure download link for what? SDK?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48178

But instead of manually downloading, it is recommended you use the automated one-click install provided by the Web Platform Installer (x86 version [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=287165)).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Is this licensed or free?

Comment: As far as I know, it's free.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you will find that. I don't know if SDK exists, however Azure doesn't run 32 bit operating systems anyway for obvious reasons. Only 64bit operating systems are supported.